# How do i move lines in a file upwards to fill gaps

Tags: c#, storage, file-handling

I am making a program to store 4 sets of values stored in 4 separate files; ID, Name, Quantity and Price. Right now ive coded it so you can choose to delete one line at a time but im having trouble filling the gap the code would leave when it runs, ive tried a for loop to iterate through the file and move everything up by one but it goes outside the bounds.

```
static void Removestock()
{
    StreamReader IDread = new StreamReader("IDTEXT.txt");
    StreamReader NAMEread = new StreamReader("NAMETEXT.txt");
    StreamReader QUANTITYread = new StreamReader("QUANTITYTEXT.txt");
    StreamReader PRICEread = new StreamReader("PRICETEXT.txt");
    
    int IDlines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("IDTEXT.txt").Length;
    int NAMElines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("NAMETEXT.txt").Length;
    int QUANTITYlines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("QUANTITYTEXT.txt").Length;
    int PRICElines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("PRICETEXT.txt").Length;
    
    bool finished = false;
    bool del = false;
    string ID = "";
    bool found = false;
    bool confirm = false;
    string t1 = "";
    string t2 = "";
    string t3 = "";
    string t4 = "";
    int count = 0;
                
    while (finished == false)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Delete a stock or return to the menu (true/false)");
            del = Boolean.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
            if (del == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Input the Stock's ID you wish to delete");
                ID = Console.ReadLine();
                            
                while (found == false)
                {
                    t1 = IDread.ReadLine();
                    t2 = NAMEread.ReadLine();
                    t3 = QUANTITYread.ReadLine();
                    t4=  PRICEread.ReadLine();
                    if (t1 == ID)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found a match!");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(t1 + "   " + t2 + "   " + t3 + "   " + t4);
                        Console.WriteLine();
    
                                   
                                    
                        confirm = Boolean.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (del == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Deleting...");
    
    
                            List<string> ID2 = new List<string>();
                            List<string> NAME = new List<string>();
                            List<int> QUANTITY = new List<int>();
                            List<double> PRICE = new List<double>();
                            int temp = count;
    
                            while (temp != IDlines-1)
                            {
                                ID2.Add(IDread.ReadLine());
                                NAME.Add(NAMEread.ReadLine());
                                QUANTITY.Add(int.Parse(QUANTITYread.ReadLine()));
                                PRICE.Add(double.Parse(PRICEread.ReadLine()));
    
                                temp = temp + 1;
                            }
        
                            IDread.Close();
                            NAMEread.Close();
                            QUANTITYread.Close();
                            PRICEread.Close();
    
                            StreamWriter IDW = new StreamWriter("IDTEXT.txt");
                            StreamWriter NMW = new StreamWriter("NAMETEXT.txt");
                            StreamWriter QUW = new StreamWriter("QUANTITYTEXT.txt");
                            StreamWriter PRW = new StreamWriter("PRICETEXT.txt");
    
                            for (int i = count; i < IDlines; i++)
                            {
                                IDW.Write(ID2[i]);
                                NMW.Write(NAME[i]);
                                QUW.Write(QUANTITY[i]);
                                PRW.Write(PRICE[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        count = count + 1; 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting System.Delete now...");
                finished = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
    
        }
    }
    IDread.Close();
    NAMEread.Close();
    QUANTITYread.Close();
    PRICEread.Close();
}
```

Ive looked into some other ways of doing this and i see where most of all the answers are coming from however i'm trying not to use System.IO.File stuff as im focusing on streamread and streamwrite
Overall im looking to move text up into empty spaces in a file ive created.
Also any help on other parts of the code you think might cause issues is appreciated

Edit: I've looked into it and CSV's seem quite complicated so i'll leave them to my next project as most people say you should install a help system which i am most definitely not ready to do yet.
Also you can ignore the fact im doing this over 4 separate files rather than one database, just imagine im only using one file for one set of data and ill just implement it 4 times.

Comment: _Why_? Just use a database. But even if we give you using a text file, why not use CSV _at the very least_? Having 4 separate text files for related data is not the best idea.

Comment: Once ive done this ill remake it with csv's instead because they look a lot more useful than what im doing, thanks for the tip

Comment: Trying to keep 4 files in sync so they match row by row is a really bad design decision IMHO. At a minimum use a CSV file, or XML, or JSON, or .... connect to a database.

Comment: _"Also any help on other parts of the code you think might cause issues is appreciated"_ => `List<double> PRICE = new List<double>();` - Only use floating point types for monetary amounts where it makes sense.

Comment: ill work on converting it to use csv or an actually useful file type now.

Comment: surely it doesnt matter if i use a floating point for money if im not doing any calculations with it, im just using it as a way to store the decimal number.

Comment: That's alright. Just be aware of the implications.

Comment: `CSV's seem quite complicated` that makes little sense - a CSV is just a text file with one record per row and Values Separated by Commas. Nothing more. What you try to do here is *infinitely* more complicated as you try to "match" strings that may have absolutely no relation between them. Nothing says that line 5 in one file is related to line 5 in another. It's a *lot* easier to have only one text file with the 4 values you want in the same row, separated by commas.

Comment: Just looking into all of the examples people use when using csv's seem a bit too high end for my skill level right now. Also right now the issue isnt with the order of the files as they are all done right and in the correct order, eventually when this issue comes up ill fix it then but right now i gotta get the delete part working.

Comment: Oh my god im so sorry i thought it was a special file type not just a text document with all the data inside of it. ill actually set that all up right now.

Comment: Please also organize your code into methods (including, but not restricted to) reading data, writing data, handling data and getting user input. Changing code or finding bugs becomes some much easier, when you can isolate it. And don't compare a boolean to true or false, it's a boolean expression in itself.

Comment: Keeping groups of arrays or lists where the items are related by index is an **anti-pattern** and poor pratice: something to avoid. Instead, create a class with fields for each of the list items, and then have ONE LIST to hold all the data. Make separate methods can write out and read-in an instance of your data.

Comment: @Fildor - wow, that is really a low-quality post you linked. It found _one_ specific case where if you contort yourself there is a _slight_ difference. For 99% of use cases `decimal` is the way to go for counting money. I do think there are times where you need to do `decimal -> double -> (do math) -> double -> decimal`, but the data itself stored should be `decimal`.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou It's not _great_ but he _does_ have a point there. You shouldn't blindly go the default route because something is "always" right or "always" wrong. When it comes to persisting values, I am completely with you. No floating point there.

Comment: @Fildor - that is true in life in general.

Comment: Removed the link. Really wasn't that great.

Answer (score 3):

Your code lacks a data model. At a minimum create an `Item` class to contain the data for each item in stock.

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

<sub>Note to use `decimal` for prices to avoid silly things like a price of `1.5999999999997` instead of `1.6`</sub>

This is `C#` and the language is primarily designed around classes and you should take advantage of that.

Within the `Item` class you can write methods to read and write data, both from the legacy 4 individual text files, and from a single CSV file.

Below is an example method to deal with data from the 4 text files, that has some basic validations and checks

```
public class Item 
{
    ...    

    /// <summary>
    /// Parse 4 lines from text files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="IDline">The id text.</param>
    /// <param name="NAMEline">The name text.</param>
    /// <param name="QUANTITYline">The quantity text.</param>
    /// <param name="PRICEline">The price text.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="Item"/> if successful, <code>null</code> otherwise.</returns>
    public static Item FromTextItems(string IDline, string NAMEline, string QUANTITYline, string PRICEline)
    {
        string ID = IDline.Trim(); // need to convert to uppercase?
        string NAME = NAMEline.Trim();

        // Validation & avoid exception when converting
        // This is the part it skips "gaps" (or empty lines)
        // as `ID` or `NAME` cannot be just whitespace.
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ID)
            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NAME)
            && int.TryParse(QUANTITYline, out int QTY)
            && decimal.TryParse(PRICEline, out decimal PRICE))
        {
            Item item = new Item()
            {
                Id = ID,
                Name = NAME,
                Quantity = QTY,
                Price = PRICE
            };
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    ...
}
```

I have also created another class, that contains multiple `Item`s and can do the overall read/write of data. I could just use a `List<Item>`, but the code below allows be to not only handle the data but also act as a dictionary and look up items from their `ID` without having to sift through all the items.

```
public class Stock : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, Item>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts the key from the specified element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The element from which to extract the key.</param>
    /// <returns>The key for the specified element.</returns>
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Item item)
    {
        return item.Id;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read data from legacy 4 text files.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="idFilePath">Text file containing ids in each row.</param>
    /// <param name="nameFilePath">Text file containing names in each row.</param>
    /// <param name="priceFilePath">Text file containing prices in each row.</param>
    /// <param name="qtyFilePath">Text file containing quantities in each row.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="Stock"/> object with data loaded.</returns>
    public static Stock ReadLegacyData(string idFilePath, string nameFilePath, string qtyFilePath, string priceFilePath)
    {
        Stock stock = new Stock();

        StreamReader IDread = new StreamReader(idFilePath);
        StreamReader NAMEread = new StreamReader(nameFilePath);
        StreamReader QUANTITYread = new StreamReader(qtyFilePath);
        StreamReader PRICEread = new StreamReader(priceFilePath);

        // Check ALL files for available data
        while (!IDread.EndOfStream && !NAMEread.EndOfStream && !QUANTITYread.EndOfStream && !PRICEread.EndOfStream)
        {
            string IDline = IDread.ReadLine();
            string NAMEline = NAMEread.ReadLine();
            string QUANTITYline = QUANTITYread.ReadLine();
            string PRICEline = PRICEread.ReadLine();

            var item = Item.FromTextItems(IDline, NAMEline, QUANTITYline, PRICEline);
            if (item != null)
            {
                stock.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return stock;
    }

}
```

This should be sufficient to replace the functionality you have now. If ou want to delete a specific item you just call `stock.Remove("XYZ")` where `XYZ` is the id of the item to be removed.

The second part of this post is to implement `CSV` file handling, with both reading and writing (including a header row).

Each line in the CSV file is handled by these methods in the `Item` class

```
public class Item 
{

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// String representation of the item. Contains all data.
    /// </summary>
    public override string ToString() => $"({Id},{Name},{Quantity},{Price:c2})";

    /// <summary>
    /// Header line for CSV file.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToCSVHead() => $"{"ID"},{"NAME"},{"QUANTITY"},{"PRICE"}";

    /// <summary>
    /// Item line for CSV file.
    /// </summary>
    public string ToCSVLine() => $"{Id},{Name},{Quantity},{Price}";

    /// <summary>
    /// Read a line from a CSV file and parse it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="line">The csv file line.</param>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="Item"/> if successful, <code>null</code> otherwise.</returns>
    public static Item FromCSVLine(string line)
    {
        // This will skip any blank lines
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            // This will skip comments that start with #
            if (!line.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                // Make sure all data is present
                if (parts.Length == 4)
                {
                    return FromTextItems(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

and the entire stock of items can deal with the file operations

```
public class Stock : System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<string, Item>
{        
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves to data to CSV file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
    public void SaveToCSV(string fileName)
    {
        FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName);
        var csv = new StreamWriter(fs);
        csv.WriteLine(Item.ToCSVHead());
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            csv.WriteLine(item.ToCSVLine());
        }
        fs.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads data from a CSV file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
    /// <returns>Stock.</returns>
    public static Stock ReadFromCSV(string fileName)
    {
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);
        var csv = new StreamReader(fs);
        while (!csv.EndOfStream)
        {
            var item = Item.FromCSVLine(csv.ReadLine());
            if (item != null)
            {
                stock.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return stock;
    }
    ...
}
```

with a very basic test code to ask for a path, read the 4 text files, and write out a `.csv.` file

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string idFilePath = "IDTEXT.txt";
        string nameFilePath = "NAMETEXT.txt";
        string qtyFilePath = "QUANTITYTEXT.txt";
        string priceFilePath = "PRICETEXT.txt";

        var stock = Stock.ReadLegacyData(idFilePath, nameFilePath, qtyFilePath, priceFilePath);

        string csvFileName = "INVENTORY.CSV";
        stock.SaveToCSV(csvFileName);

        Process.Start(csvFileName);
    }
}
```

---

It is a good idea also to implement `IComparable<Item>` and `IEquatable<Item>` on `Item` based on their `ID` value. A typical implementation is

```
public class Item : IComparable<Item>, IEquatable<Item>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    ...

    #region IEquatable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares the current instance with another object of the same type and returns an integer that indicates whether the current instance precedes, follows, or occurs in the same position in the sort order as the other object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">An object to compare with this instance.</param>
    /// <returns>A value that indicates the relative order of the objects being compared. The return value has these meanings:
    /// Value
    /// Meaning
    /// Less than zero
    /// This instance precedes <paramref name="other" /> in the sort order.
    /// Zero
    /// This instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as <paramref name="other" />.
    /// Greater than zero
    /// This instance follows <paramref name="other" /> in the sort order.</returns>
    public int CompareTo(Item other)
        => Id.CompareTo(other?.Id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(Item)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Item item && Equals(item);

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="Item"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Item other) => Id.Equals(other.Id);

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="Item"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = -1817952719;
            hc = (-1521134295) * hc + Id.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Very exhaustive. I hope this isn't too much for OP. @GGayCriminal : This _is_ a good answer, maybe don't try to understand _all of it_ at once.

Comment: I made some minor modifications to the code with regard to how to specify the text files to read. I am done with updates and edits, pending any glaring errors I might have missed.

Comment: @Fildor - I think this is very basic level data/file management stuff and if the _op_ has trouble understanding then they have no business in writing code that other people might depend on. For their own personal gain and understanding, I think my post illustrates all the moving pieces needed to provide the functionality requested. What I am trying to show is that each class `Item` and `Stock` should handle its own stuff at their own level in order to glue the functional parts together.

Comment: Absolutely agree. As I said: great answer. Just wanted to encourage OP to not "give up" because it's a lot (seemingly). And I don't believe this going to be "production" code, but a learning project ... so, it's fine to digest in increments :)